# Background color in UWP App

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.forms, uwp-xaml, xamarin.uwp

We recently upgraded from windows framework from 10.0.10240 to 10.0.15063. We have struck at a `button` design issue where a `background color` is appearing as grey. Before upgrade this color was not appearing. We need to remove this grey color behind text.

[image: After windows framework upgrade]

On hover of image also the same foreground color is appearing:

[image]

`Xamarin.Forms.Button` doesn't have a Foreground color equivalent property. I tried custom renderer with setting `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.FormsButton.Foreground` but no effect on button control.

Is there any Style Setter I can try to resolve the issue? Any help please.

**Edit**

This was solved by applying Background color, earlier I was setting Foreground on button,

```
this.Control.BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush() { Opacity = 1, Color= Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent };
```

Comment: If you're referring to the grey rectangle, thats not foreground, that's the Background property of the button, the Foreground property is usually attributed to the colour of the text, and there are seperate onhover colours available to select and amend.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue in my side. Have you custom button `ContentTemplate` or  button `Style` in your uwp client project?

Comment: Thanks for your help.@Digitalsa1nt Its BackgroundColor property, and manually setting that to transparent it worked.
@NicoZhu-MSFT I'm using custom style property on button on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/windows/apps/mt299109.aspx, but in recent release the issue appeared. Now manually setting `this.Control.BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush() { Opacity = 1, Color= Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent };` worked good.

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by applying Background color.

```
this.Control.BackgroundColor = new SolidColorBrush(){Opacity = 1,Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Transparent };
```